# What are the character limitations to Django model's related_name in a relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I noticed that you can't have `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`, or any other mathematical character symbol in the `related_name`. You also can't use `:`, `|`, or `.`.

If you have any of the above characters in `related_name`, although Django's `models.py` will validate, whenever you do a query lookup it'll throw an error like

```
Q(userprofile.user__place__managers=user)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

The reason I want to use a special character is because I like to have my `related_name` in the form of `{class_name}{field_name}`. So for example for the `UserProfile` model class I would do something like

```
class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile-user')
    user_type = models.ManyToManyFields(UserType, related_name='userprofile-user_type')
```

That way when I do a query that involves a following a relationship backward, but still know *how* I am following it backward. For example, if I simply do

```
user_type = models.ManyToManyFields(UserType, related_name='user_type')
```

then I can access `UserType` from `User` doing `User.objects.get(pk=1).user_type.all()`. But this makes it looks like `user_type` is a field of `User`.

Instead if I could do something like `User.objects.get(pk=1).userprofile-user_type.all()` then I would know that I am going from `User` to `UserProfile` to `UserType`.

Well my way of thinking is probably in the minority and I would assume that most people would just do `related_name='user_type'` or maybe even use default `user_type_set`.

Another question would be: **What is the good style for naming `related_name`?**

Comment: Answer has good info, but it's rather long and hard to skim for meaning. For the TL;DR crowd: just stick with (lowercase) alpha and underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**userprofile-user_type** is not a valid python identifier.

Python thinks you are trying to subtract user_type from userprofile.

In your specific case `profiles` would be a good enough related manager name.

So that when you have a a UserType instance:

```
utype = UserType.objects.get(...)
utype.profiles.all()
```

It would give you all the profiles associated with that user type.

Also there is no ManyToManyField**s**, remove the "s".

Try not to be more verbose than what is needed to convey the meaning of a relationship.
The field name inside the related name is redundant and unnecessary.

**UPDATE:**
Please do not name it `userprofiles_from_user_type`

It's like having this:

```
class Person:
    def PersonWalk(self):
        ...
```

Instead of:

```
class Person:
    def walk(self):
        ...
```

Let me give you a more complex example with an intermediate table

```
class Service(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Person(Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonServiceRel', null=True, related_name='friends', symmetrical=False)

class PersonServiceRel(Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='provided_services')
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='consumed_services')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
```

Now let's say we have people providing some kind of services to each other and I want
to know if the user "rantaplan" provides "tracking" service and to whom.

```
rantaplan = Person.objects.get(name='rantanplan')
tracking = Service.objects.get(name='tracking')
PersonServiceRel.objects.filter(provider=rantaplan, service=tracking)
# or
rantaplan.provided_services.filter(service=tracking)
```

Note the PersonServicesRel the fields 'provider' and 'consumer' and their related_manager.
Also note the necessary query. I think it's quite readable.

So I suggest that you name your fields and related managers depending on their purpose and usage, with as little verbosity as possible.

Comment: I'm now thinking about using `userprofiles_from_user_type` as the `related_name`. It's a bit long, but it seems to really make sense to me. You wrote that "the field name inside the related name is redundant and unnecessary". So what is your naming scheme for `related_name`?

Comment: @hobbes3 I updated my answer. If you need further explanation or simpler examples give me a shout